# How show recently sold items in a specific page using shortcode in WordPress WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

I have a WooCommerce website for digital products. The products that sold generally have a custom tag named "Recently Sold". But, I want to show all the sold items in a specific page where only the sold items will be displayed.

I got a plugin "WooCommerce Toolkit" Which show recently sold items in the sidebar and another is "Woo recently sold items list" which show recently sold item only in the single product page.

I want to show all the sold items on a page like "Sold" page.

I hope it now makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_shortcode( 'sold_products', 'wc_products_allsold' );

function wc_products_allsold() {

    //  Get last week orders
    $all_orders = wc_get_orders(
    array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => array_map( 'wc_get_order_status_name', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
        'return' => 'ids',
    )
    );

    // Sum quantities purchased

    $count               = 0;
    $produt_sale_list    = array();
    foreach ( $all_orders as $all_order ) {
        $order   = wc_get_order( $all_order );
        $items   = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            $produt_sale_list[ $item->get_name() ][]     = $item[ 'qty' ];
            $count                                   = $count + absint( $item[ 'qty' ] );
        }
    }

    foreach ( $produt_sale_list as $produt_sold => $value ) {
        echo "<p>$produt_sold sold: " . array_sum( $value ) . "</p>";
    }
    if ( $count > 0 )
        echo "<p>Recent sales: $count</p>";
}
```

Add the shortcode `[sold_products]` into the page where you want to display all sold products.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work.. It is working but shows like http://prntscr.com/sd6y25..Is it possible to show the products with name and image like the product page?

Comment: This will cause the text to be rendered on the page, but for it to render where the shortcode is located the strings should be returned from the function instead of echoed.