# Woocommerce sold out products from specific category only

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Fallowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640737/how-show-recently-sold-items-in-a-specific-page-using-shortcode-in-wordpress-woo) article. I am trying to make the same thing but limited to single category only called vip-betta-fish.

```
add_shortcode( 'sold_products', 'wc_products_allsold' );

function wc_products_allsold() {
    
    $categories = array('vip-betta-fish');

    //  Get last week orders
    $all_orders = wc_get_orders(
            array(
                'limit'  => -1,
                'status' => array_map( 'wc_get_order_status_name', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
                'return' => 'ids',
            )
    );

    // Sum quantities purchased

    $count               = 0;
    $produt_sale_list    = array();

    echo '<ul class="products">';
    $a = 5;
    foreach ( $all_orders as $all_order ) {
        
        $order   = wc_get_order( $all_order );
        $items   = $order->get_items();
        
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $produt_sale_list[ $item->get_name() ][] = $item[ 'qty' ];
                $count = $count + absint( $item[ 'qty' ] );
                $product = $item->get_product();
                $url = get_permalink( $product->get_id() );
                $novo = $item->get_product_id();

            }
        
        }
        
        $a++;
//      var_dump($product);
//      die();
            echo    '<li class="product col-md-4 ' . $product->get_name() . $a .'"><div class="tm-product-box product-hover-style2"><a href="'.$url.'" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><div class="tm-product-image-box"><div class="product-labels"><span class="sold product-label">Sold</span></div>'. $product->get_image() .'</div></a><div class="tm-product-content"><a class="tm-product-title-link" href="'.$url.'"><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . $product->get_name() . '</h2></a><!-- .tm-product-title-link --><span class="price"><span class="woocs_price_code" data-product-id="3827"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>' . $product->get_regular_price() . '</bdi></span></span></span></div></div></li>';

    }
        echo '</ul>';
}
```

This code was working for some time, but suddenly it is forcing 500 error.
I would appriciate any help on how to make it work.

Thank you.

Comment: The part that is causing error is this->  if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {